# Failing to link GLEW library

Tags: c++, c, opengl, makefile

this is my makefile:

```
### OUTPUT ###
BUILD = Build

### SOURCES ###
SRC = Src/main\
      Src/Game/Game\
      Src/Shader/Shader

### OBJECTS ###
OBJ = $(addsuffix .o, $(addprefix $(BUILD)/, $(SRC)))

### INCLUDES ###
INC = -ID:/Development/OpenGL/Glfw/include/GLFW\
      -ID:/Development/OpenGL/Glew/glew-2.1.0/include/GL\
      -ID:/Development/OpenGL/Glm/glm-0.9.9.8/glm\
      -ISrc/Game\
      -ISrc/Shader/

### LIBRARIES ###
LIB = -LD:/Development/OpenGL/Glew/glew-2.1.0/lib/Release/Win32 -lglew32s\
      -LD:/Development/OpenGL/Glfw/lib-mingw -lglfw3\
      -lopengl32

### LINKER FLAGS ###
LFLAGS = $(LIB)

### COMPILER FLAGS
CFLAGS = $(INC)

### COMPILER ###
CC = g++

all: $(BUILD)/test.exe

$(BUILD)/test.exe: $(OBJ)
    @echo LINKING $^
    @$(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
    @echo COMPILING $<
    @mkdir -p $(subst /,\,$(dir $@))
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -M -MT $@ -o $(patsubst %.o, %.d, $@) $<
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

-include $(OBJ:.o=.d) 

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    @echo CLEANING......
    @@rm -rf $(BUILD)/*
```

i am specifying the needed libraries here:

```
### LIBRARIES ###
LIB = -LD:/Development/OpenGL/Glew/glew-2.1.0/lib/Release/Win32 -lglew32s\
      -LD:/Development/OpenGL/Glfw/lib-mingw -lglfw3\
      -lopengl32
```

and linking them here:

```
$(BUILD)/test.exe: $(OBJ)
    @echo LINKING $^
    @$(CC) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

the errors i am getting are:

```
LINKING Build/Src/main.o Build/Src/Game/Game.o Build/Src/Shader/Shader.o
Build/Src/Shader/Shader.o:Shader.cpp:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
Build/Src/Shader/Shader.o:Shader.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `__glewCreateShader'
Build/Src/Shader/Shader.o:Shader.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `__glewShaderSource'
Build/Src/Shader/Shader.o:Shader.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `__glewCompileShader'
Build/Src/Shader/Shader.o:Shader.cpp:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `__glewCreateShader'
Build/Src/Shader/Shader.o:Shader.cpp:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `__glewShaderSource'
Build/Src/Shader/Shader.o:Shader.cpp:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `__glewCompileShader'
```

also i have defined `GLEW_STATIC`:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "glew.h"
```

i am using mingw32 and i'm calling the makefile with `mingw32-make all`
I have no idea why it can't find those symbols...i've been trying to figure it out for 2 hours..

EDIT:
Here is the actual linking command:

`g++ -LD:/Development/OpenGL/Glew/glew-2.1.0/lib/Release/Win32 -lglew32s -LD:/Development/OpenGL/Glfw/lib-mingw -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -o Build/test.exe Build/Src/main.o Build/Src/Game/Game.o Build/Src/Shader/Shader.o`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a single-pass linker (like almost all linkers today) the order of items is critical.  In particular, you have to make sure that all your object files appear on the link line *first*, before any libraries.  Secondly you have to make sure that libraries are ordered correctly, so that the higher level libraries come earlier and the lower level libraries (that other libraries depend on) come afterwards.

You need to extract your library flags into two distinct parts: one part that has linker control options (such as `-L`) and another part that contains the actual libraries themselves (such as `-l`).

In standard makefiles these parts are placed into the variables `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS`, respectively:

```
LDFLAGS = -LD:/Development/OpenGL/Glew/glew-2.1.0/lib/Release/Win32 \
          -LD:/Development/OpenGL/Glfw/lib-mingw

LDLIBS = -lglew32s -lglfw3 -lopengl32
```

I don't know enough about GLEW to know if the `LDLIBS` are ordered properly you may need to experiment.

Then, write your link rule like this:

```
$(BUILD)/test.exe: $(OBJ)
        @echo LINKING $^
        @$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

Comment: Oh yes..i forgot about the order...Thank you so much!!

Comment: Are there any flags that *must* go before the `-o $@ $^`? Normally I just put all of them at the end of the command...

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any linker flags that need to go before the object files in modern compilers.  In older, traditional UNIX programs often _all_ the options had to come before any non-options (in these linkers `-l` was a special case).  Once the program sees the first non-option argument it assumes all subsequent words are arguments, not options, even if they start with `-`.  But most modern programs allow options and arguments to be mixed together so this is not an issue.